# using useRef to update input and prevent rerenderings

Tags: reactjs

Is using useRef in the following way bad? I want to prevent rerenderings.

```
const Component = ({onGenerate}) => {
   const charactersCountRef = useRef();
   const nameRef = useRef(null);

   const handleOnInput = (event) => {
      charactersCountRef.current.value = `${event.target.value.length}/32 Characters(Minimum 6 characters)`;
   }

  const handleGenerate = useCallback(async (event) => {
        onGenerate(apiKeyNameRef.current.value);
  }, [apiKeyNameRef, onGenerate]);


   return (
       <input
          ref={apiKeyNameRef}
          onInput={handleOnInput}
        />    
        <input 
          ref={charactersCountRef} 
          readOnly={true}  
          value={`0/32 Characters (Minimum 6 characters)`}
        />
        <button onClick={handleGenerate}>Generate</button>
    );
}
```

The component won't rerender but I am not sure this is good practice in react.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent re-renders?

Comment: I think about performance. Maybe It's not much difference to use useState instead for this small component but is my current approach with useRef wrong? Is there any good reason why I should avoid this?